# Android ListView with a checkbox

Tags: android, android-listview

I've now spent a full day on trying to get a custom row to load.  There seem to be plenty of examples here on StackOverflow and other places on how to bind a checkbox to a row of data within an Android listview, but they all seem to be incomplete.

Here's what I have (row.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@drawable/row_bk"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ItemID"
    android:layout_weight="0" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:layout_width="0dp" android:textColor="#666"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:padding="5dp" android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="17dip" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkCheck" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:clickable="true"></CheckBox>

</LinearLayout>
```

In code, I have a SimpleCursorAdapter, populating the ListView.

```
    Cursor oLoop = db
            .rawQuery(
            "select _id, title, is_checked from tbl",null);

    startManagingCursor(oLoop);

    String[] from = new String[] { "_id", "title", "is_checked" };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ItemID, R.id.Title, R.id.chkCheck };

    SimpleCursorAdapter  oList =
     new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.task_item_row, oLoop, from,
     to);  

     setListAdapter(oList);
```

Past this, I'm not really sure what to do.  If someone could point me at a good example, that would be great.  The goal is to actually be able to toggle the checkboxes.

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

The next step is to implement [ViewBinder.setViewValue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29)

It would look something like this:

```
getViewAdapter().setViewBinder(
    new ViewBinder(){
        public boolean setViewAdapter(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
            <JavaType> object = cursor.get<JavaType>(columnIndex);

            boolean isHandled = false;
            if(view.getId() == R.id.checkBox){
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                cb.setChecked(isObjectChecked(object));
                // object depends on your underlying data type 
                // in the data base, use the debugger to find the actually implemented type.
                isHandled = true;
            }

            return isHandled;
        }
    }
);
```

This can be a very powerful method with conditionally visible views and loading Uri's from the network, etc.

Comment: Yup, that did it!  That was the piece I was missing!!  Definitely, not an obvious step either.  I'll have to document this somewhere for posterity.

Comment: @LTMOD Its in the [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) documentation.